# What's thrashing MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have several node services running, each using a Mongoose driver. I have Nagios warnings setup for too many queries per second, and these have started to fire lately. What's the best way to track down which service is blasting all the queries?

Comment: how many is too many? are you sure your warning thresholds aren't set too low?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky it could be that my thresholds are low, but the concern is that this does not coincide with heavy traffic, so the concern is a process that's needlessly thrashing it.

Comment: if the monitoring is not excluding certain internal system processes (like TTLMonitor every 60 seconds, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd log into the mongo shell when this is happening and run db.currentOp(true):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/

Don't know your specific setup but if you have multiple clients hitting the database the currentOp.client field in the results is very useful in tracking down the source of rogue queries.

Comment: This combined with netstat looks like it'll give me what I need. Thanks @jpsf!

Answer (score 1):

first, you can use [profiling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/):

```
db.setProfilingLevel(level, slowms)
```

This will write to the queries that takes more than "slowms" into system.profile collection.
Note profiling itself will slow down your system. So try not to do it in peak hours. And be careful with the slowms parameter so that you don't record too many queries.

Secondly, have a look at your log:

```
tail -f /var/log/mongodb.log
```

It will record slow queries.

**EDIT:** if you are looking for which client sends most queries, try [mongotop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/) which will give you a per collection read/write overview. Or [mongostate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) which will give you a per database overview. It's not that straight forward, but it helps you to analyse the stress. Or you can have a look at the network traffic with Linux tool iftop.

Comment: The way I understand it, the OP has a problem of too many queries sent by a client, it's not about particular queries being slow, but the number of queries. While it's possible to log *all* requests using the profiler, that will cause an insert for every other operation, which in turn modifies the access patterns too heavily.

Comment: true. I add more info about per collection and per database overview with mongotop/mongostat. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks yaoxing. I did not know about mongostat and the profiling level. But as @mnemosyn suggested, the trouble is not with heavy queries, but actually what are probably very light queries happening thousands of times per second. Isolating it to a particular database and collection may help narrow it down, but I'm interested in a way to tell specifically which process is doing the queries. Like a way to tag each Mongo connection with a unique ID, then trace the queries back to that mongo connection.

Comment: I see your point. It's because mongodb is unlikely to provide per client/connection stats, thus I'm trying to provide closest solution to narrow it down. Hope it helps.

Comment: My opinion,connection is variable. there maybe new ones connected, and old ones may disconnect. Thus if mongo db provides such stats, it will have to store all the history data. That's why I think it's impossible. Even if it does do so, with connection pool working, you're likely to see a bunch of overwhelm connections.